# Multiplying out negated terms in boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, algebra

I'm just learning boolean algebra at the moment. I read that for XOR we can rearrange the expression

1. (A + B) . ¬(A + B)
2. = A.¬A + A.¬B + B.¬A + B.¬B
3. = A.¬B + B.¬A

I can understand this but I'm unsure how I would proceed multiplying out an expression like

- (A + B) . (¬A + ¬B).

If I just try and naively multiply out all the terms that will bring me to the same result as XOR but the truth table is different. What are the rules on multiplying out negated terms?

Comment: This is a good question for http://www.mathoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about that site. These overflow sites seem to be springing up like wildfire now!

Comment: All this time, I thought people were being sarcastic about the website, I never clicked it until now.

Comment: To facilitate discussion, I've taken the liberty to number your formulae. They're now numbered "1", "2", "3" and "bullet" (best I could do with the markdown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first expression isn't an xor, try making this substitution:

```
 Z = A+B
```

Comment: I don't know what good the substitution would do, but I believe you're right about the first expression not being an XOR.

Comment: what do you get when you make the substitution in the first expression?

Comment: (It just makes the truth value more obvious)

Comment: Ah, I see... you're demonstrating that (1) is always false. Yep, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Well spotted. That is actually a typo in the book I'm using I think.

He originally states it as (A + B) . ¬(A.B) but then proceeds to start with (A + B) . ¬(A + B) in the multiplying out example.

Comment: OK. Using De Morgan 

(A+B). ¬(A.B) = (A+B).(¬A+¬B) and I can follow the multiplication out from there. Maybe the author quietly used De Morgan without specifying it and just took it as read the equivalence would be apparent. The book doesn't actually use the ¬ symbol but rather a continuous bar over the whole second A+B expression that I couldn't figure out how to reproduce here. Maybe I misinterpreted that as equivalent to ¬(A+B) in my attempted ASCII translation.

Comment: sounds like a typo to me.  \bar{(A+B)} == ¬(A+B)

Comment: Thanks. It all makes more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You can throw this kinda thing at Wolfram Alpha. Here's what I did:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+(a+or+b)+and+(not+a+or+not+b)

Please click on the link to view the results! Does that truth table look like what you thought it should, or not?

Answer (score 1):

You think the truth table is different?

Try evaluating it yourself.

Comment: Doh! I'm not sure how I convinced myself that they were different. So basically it should never make any difference then if the negation applies to the whole bracketed expression or individual component(s)?

Comment: Oh no, big diff. That's what DeMorgan is all about. If you move the 'not' into the parentheses, you have to invert the conjunction inside the parentheses.

Comment: Yes I had thought that I had got myself into trouble with doing something like that earlier. I'll try and revisit that example with the help of Wolfram Alpha!

Answer (score 1):

You need [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demorgan%27s_law)

Answer (score 0):

Answers here are not clear to me. I believe there's a typo in how you typed #1. It is a contradiction:

1. `(A + B) * -(A + B)`
2. `(A + B) * -A * -B`
3. `-A * -B * A + -A * -B * B`
4. `0`

If #1 were `(A + B) * (-A + -B)` instead:

1. `(A + B) * (-A + -B)`
2. `-A * (A + B) + -B * (A + B)`
3. `-A * A + -A * B + -B * A + -B * B`
4. `-A * B + -B * A`

That's how you distribute AND over OR.